# Pollable StreamListener or MessageSource for RabbitMQ Queue

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit project that sends messages to an rabbit exchange `errorEx` in case of errors in the flow.
I want to periodically(once in 5 mins) listen from the queue and process it.

Is there any way I can have a Pollable `@StreamListener`?
OR Can I configure a rabbitMQ `org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource` so I can build a `IntegrationFlow` with a Poller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Integration AMQP doesn't provide a pollable adapter. `@StreamListener` only supports `Subscribable` channels.

You could use a custom `MessageSource` that uses a `RabbitTemplate` `receive()` operation to fetch messages.

Or, you could use the message-driven adapter and `stop()/start()` it as needed.

Comment: Used a `CustomMessageSource` where I was able to do `rabbitTemplate.receive()`. Then used it with poller in a IntegrationFlow. `IntegrationFlows.from(customMessageSource, c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10000, 10000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1))) .channel(retryChannel()).get()`